# Conversion of existing Java dynamic web project

Tags: java, servlets, applet

I have existing Java dynamic web project which contains applet and servlets, since applet and servlets are no longer supported, so is there any way to convert my existing code to any other web technology which will work on any browser.

Comment: "[...] servlets are no longer supported [...]" ?!?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose on browser

Comment: _Servlets could in principle communicate over any client–server protocol, but they are most often used with the HTTP protocol._ From wikipedia. I'm still using servlets.

Comment: Servlets are a server side technology. What do browsers have to do with it? Your question lacks many things, including knowledge about the topics you are speaking about.

Comment: @Gatusko Not only you. Every framework that does HTTP communication (for example JAX-RS frameworks such as Jersey or Resteasy) uses servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Web Start, which browsers still seem to support. I wouldn't recommend it though as it still has random issues, and I can't even get Oracle's own runnable tutorial examples to work.

I fear the only future-proof option is to go fully web page or app mode (perhaps with help of JavaFX which translates to web pages nicely).